# Keyboard does not show?

Tags: dart, flutter

doing a simple Flutter app, but for some reason the keyboard won't show when I select the TextFields? I have browsed around and can't see anything that I am missing? All good when I run Flutter Doctor.

(Please ignore the imports, haven't gotten to the the methods where they will be used yet)

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:t2/helpers/currentuser.dart';


class Login extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  _LoginState createState() => new _LoginState();
}

class _LoginState extends State<Login> {


  final TextEditingController _usrTextController = new TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _pwdTextcontroller = new TextEditingController();
  CurrentUser cUser = new CurrentUser();
  // cUser.loginUser();

  @override
  Widget build (BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text('Member Login')),
        body: new Container(
          child: new Center(
            child: new Column( 
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                new TextField(
                  controller: _usrTextController,
                  decoration: new InputDecoration(hintText: 'Username'),
                ),
                new TextField(
                  controller: _pwdTextcontroller,
                  decoration: new InputDecoration(hintText: 'Password'),
                )
              ],
            ),
          )
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: hi @RobertBenedetto I've used the same code and I don't see any problem bringing up the keyboard. please can you share a small image or video so that we can understand what you are trying to achieve

Comment: also which device you're using and the version of flutter (run flutter doctor and paste the output) might help.

Comment: Have you used emulator ?

Answer (score 2):

This turned out to be a setting in the simulator. It was set to hardware keyboard, not software.